# Syntax error: parse error, when creating a regression test checking empty tables

Tags: sql, teradata

I am creating a regression test query that shall check if tables are populated or not. This is done by getting the first row in each table A,B,C and if its id exist it shall get value "Y". If not then value "N". I created the code below to do the following but I get Syntax error: parse error. Can somebody please tell me what's wrong?

```
SELECT 

Case
    When  EXISTS( A.Id) THEN 'Y'
    ELSE 'N'
END AS A_exist,

Case
    When  EXISTS( B.Id) THEN 'Y'
    ELSE 'N'
END AS B_exist,

Case
    When  EXISTS( C.Id) THEN 'Y'
    ELSE 'N'
END AS C_exist

FROM
(select top 1 * from Table_A) A
(select top 1 * from Table_B) B
(select top 1 * from Table_C) C
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can force a row for empty tables using a `COUNT`:

```
SELECT
   CASE WHEN a.CNT = 1 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS A_exist,
   CASE WHEN b.CNT = 1 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS B_exist,
   CASE WHEN c.CNT = 1 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS C_exist
FROM
 (
   SELECT COUNT(*) AS CNT
   WHERE EXISTS(SELECT  * FROM Table_A) 
 ) AS a,
 (
   SELECT COUNT(*) AS CNT
   WHERE EXISTS(SELECT  * FROM Table_B) 
 ) AS b,
 (
   SELECT COUNT(*) AS CNT
   WHERE EXISTS(SELECT  * FROM Table_C)
 ) AS c;
```

But why don't you return one row per table instead of one column? It's much easier to extend:

```
SELECT 'Table_A' AS "Table", CASE WHEN COUNT(*) = 1 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS "Exists?"
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Table_A) 
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Table_B', CASE WHEN COUNT(*) = 1 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Table_B) 
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Table_C', CASE WHEN COUNT(*) = 1 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Table_C)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you use sql-server? Does this work?

```
SELECT 

Case
    When  EXISTS(select * from Table_A) THEN 'Y'
    ELSE 'N'
END AS A_exist,

Case
    When  EXISTS(select * from Table_B) THEN 'Y'
    ELSE 'N'
END AS B_exist,

Case
    When  EXISTS(select * from Table_C) THEN 'Y'
    ELSE 'N'
END AS C_exist
```

Comment: Hi. I get the feedback that TOP N is not supported in sub query. I'm using Teradata.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below query.

```
SELECT 

Case
    When   A.Id IS NOT NULL THEN 'Y'
    ELSE 'N'
END AS A_exist,

Case
    When  B.Id IS NOT NULL THEN 'Y'
    ELSE 'N'
END AS B_exist,

Case
    When  C.Id IS NOT NULL THEN 'Y'
    ELSE 'N'
END AS C_exist

FROM
(select top 1 * from Table_A) A,
(select top 1 * from Table_B) B,
(select top 1 * from Table_C) C
;
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that in case one table is empty then I will not get value 'N' but instead the whole reult set is just an empty table. How can I solve that?

Comment: In that case this one should work : SELECT 
Case
    When   A.Id IS NOT NULL THEN 'Y'
    ELSE 'N'
END AS A_exist,
'N' AS B_EXIST,
'N' AS C_exist
FROM 
(select top 1 * from Table_A) A
UNION 
SELECT
'N' AS A_EXIST,
Case
    When  B.Id IS NOT NULL THEN 'Y'
    ELSE 'N'
END AS B_exist,
'N' AS C_EXIST
FROM
(select top 1 * from Table_B) B
UNION
SELECT
'N' AS A_EXIST,
'N' AS B_EXIST,
Case
    When  C.ID IS NOT NULL THEN 'Y'
    ELSE 'N'
END AS C_exist
FROM
(select top 1 * from Table_C) C

;